# opening the outlook using VBA code in citrix

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

How to open the Outlook in citrix using the VBA code ?

I want to copy the details from the excel and paste it in the outlook and make it ready to be send please help me with the coding

Answer (score -1):

See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0).